# Why is there no review queue on the mobile site?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, mobile-site

Not sure if this is asked and answered elsewhere. (Searching Meta isn't always fruitful due to rampant down voting!)

The mobile interface that just debuted the other day is a massive improvement over the old. But, how about a review queue?  I can access it from full-site mode; I know there isn't a compatibility issue.

While we're at it, flag count and other user features would be nice additions to the mobile interface.

Comment: While I've wished for this myself from time to time, I'm not totally sure that I think it's a good idea to discourage typing when doing reviews (by doing them on a device that makes typing difficult). I feel we already have far too many reviewers hitting close without writing a comment to explain why, which makes it a pretty unfriendly place for new users. But, I guess the problem here is the reviewers, not the device they choose to use.

Comment: I type so much from my phone, that I barely notice anymore. Let's face it, the world has gone mobile, we should embrace it!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think Stack Exchange are missing a big trick here.

The most popular sites on the network are generally for programming/technical matters, and gaming (us!). *All the time* when I'm in a position to ask or answer a question on these sites, I'm at a computer.

What do I want to do when I'm not at the computer (like, on a bus or train)? **Review queues**. Basic reviewing is something that works well with a mobile interface too: less typing, more button mashing. Queue counter widgets for my homescreen? I dare not even dream.

If the SE app had review functionality in it, I would be in it *all the time*.

Comment: I strongly approve of the diamond porkchop.

Answer (score 2):

Not every part of the site is available in a "mobile" version on the mobile site. The same applies when using the Stack Exchange application for Android. This has always been the case to date but adding mobile review functions [is on the list of things to do in the long term](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148616/review-option-on-mobile-phone-not-available).

As you've noticed, for the time being you can access the standard desktop review queue to handle reviews that way by browsing to /review and this works fine for the act of reviewing with a bit of zooming and page scrolling.

Comment: This would be easier to accept if they allowed a link to the full-site version of the queue from the mobile edition.

Comment: Looking at the date of that post, it's a "longer" term goal.  So, 1.5 years later, I don't feel unjustified in asking for it again.

Comment: Totally, I do so much reviewing from mobile that I've just come to accept using the desktop site. A nice mobile-centric UI for reviewing would be awesome, though.

Answer (score 2):

The main issue with it seems to be fitting all the necessary information on the screen in a way that isn't confusing or hard to read. As you know, reviews should offer as much context and information as possible and represent the information in a nice way to the reviewer. Mobile screens are often either very small making it hard to accomplish or the screen is big enough to use the desktop layout without any issue at all.

For the android app, there seem to be [other issues as well](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215841/add-review-queues-to-android-app#comment697857_215841):

> This also assumes that Stack Exchange would be alright with implementing API calls to fetch review items and accept responses for those items. Honestly, that sounds a bit sketchy.

Comment: This can be defeated with some mobile wizardry.  The answer is never "It can't be done."  Rather it should be, "We haven't figured out how to do it, yet."

Comment: @DavidM The answer isn't "it can't be done", they just have more important things to develop first, and need to figure out the design.

Comment: That, I'll buy!  Though, as Fredley says "I would be in it all the time."

Answer (score 2):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

With the recent removal of the dedicated mobile site in favour of a [responsive site design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/367609/179041) catering to both mobile and desktop, you can now access the review queues (and everything else) from a mobile browser.